# CollectionView doesn't appear after API call in Xamarin UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin.uwp

Before API integration we were able to view the Collection view content but after the time of API call integration for CollectionView something wrong happens and I am not able to get the entire view of that Content Page. If you comment on the Collection view from that Xaml code it will work perfectly fine. Could anyone help with this? 
This specific behavior happens in UWP only.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Share your code and please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many type of trials I found one solution that to initialize the ItemSource of Collection view in constructor of ViewModel and again adding data from API it will work for you.
Also need to check that SelectedItem parameter should not be their in that Collectionview and provide HeightRequest for the CollectionView as well.